# Application_Error event not being fired with CustomError page in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-error-pages, global-asax

I have an asp.net website and i have a block of code in my global.asax's Application_Error event to send the error details(stack trace etc..) as an email to my email id.Also i have Custom error page set in my web.config.I published the website in release mode and deployed to production.When i access the site,I got some errors and i was shown the custom error page i set in my web.config.But i never received an email about the error.I am sure the email server is working in production server.I have email sending code in my app which works well. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: In my case I get this issue only when I publish on IIS 7. It works fine on visual studio development web server.

Comment: Suddenly it started working. I don't know what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ for error logging and reporting.